# "CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match", incorrect "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in Response Header

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We have a multi-tenant web application hosted on IIS with two headers (SiteA and SiteB). The application uses Autodesk Forge Viewer on the client side. Everything was working fine until last week which this started happening:
when browsing the application with url "http://www.siteA.com" it works fine. now if we browse same application using url "http://www.siteB.com" in another tab the viewer does not load and we have two errors in the debug:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/6.2.3/lmvworker.min.js. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘http://www.siteA.com’).

and

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/6.2.3/res/locales/en/allstrings.json. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘http://www.siteA.com’).

as the error suggests although the Origin in the Request header of the call is "http://www.siteB.com" the returning "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in the response header is "http://www.siteA.com" !

now if someone else (or using another browser) we do the same but other way (first site B then A) we have site B working fine but site A giving the error with wrong response header.

Has anyone ever had such problem? is this a CDN cache issue with any possible Autodesk Forge CDN servers updated? 
Any help to guide me in the right direction will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could it have been caused by stale cache? Or any proxy acting up in the middle? Sounds like browser behavior rather than our CDN - just tried `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/6.2.3/res/locales/en/allstrings.json` and the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the header was *

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I doubt it has to do anything to browser for bellow reasons:
- tried accessing both sites from different browsers (Chrome and Firefox) same result
- using different browsers I tried different order (A then B causing B to not work) and in another browser (B then A and A didn't work)

Comment: Also I have tried accessing both A and B from different networks, internal and from outside the network, same behavior, so it can't be a proxy too

Comment: one more thing: when you call a script by typing the url in browser it always has Access-Control-Allow-Origin as *. reason for that is it is not called from a website page therefore it has no origin...

Comment: Just tried loading `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/6.2.3/res/locales/en/allstrings.json` with Viewer and still had `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as `*` - didn't think our servers would behave differently as it's supposed to allow all origins ... if the issue persists try set up a proxy to fetch Viewer's assets...see an example [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/happy-2020-forge-make-proxy-and-cache-sample-your-new-year-resolution)

Comment: I'm not really sure how you get *. no matter how I load the a page with a viewer (from c:/... or localhost or siteA.com/...) I never get * it always has the address (except when it's loaded from c:/... which the value is NULL).
may I ask where do you check to the value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin ?

Comment: @BryanHuang can you please follow this up with your engineering/infrastructure team ans see if there was any changes that could cause Access-Control-Allow-Origin to be different from what you see?
no matter where/how we try we do not get * 
this has to be a new change. there's no other explanation as this application was working fine for the past two years and this error has started to happen since past two weeks.
Appreciate your help here.

Comment: See the wildcard I received from the browser's network activity [here](https://imgur.com/p9WJRNn) and our Engineering has confirmed there was no change during this period of time ...

Comment: well obviously there's something changed. this is a test model app I donwloaded from Autodesk github, and cannot see *, no matter how I run it: https://imgur.com/a/MDXllh2

Comment: try [this example](https://output.jsbin.com/disopoq/) and see if you can get the wildcard... and code is [here](https://jsbin.com/disopoq/edit)

Comment: Yes I can see the wildcard. however the script is loading from different address in this example. can you please try using:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.js?v=7.*

Comment: I can change our application to use script from https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/  if that is a standard server?

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the exact same behaviour. In our case it are 2 different sites with 2 complete different domains.

We are using these url's for loading script and CSS

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css

I have tested it in the latest Chrome / Firefox and in both browsers I get the error.

What I did:

- Visit site A => Everything works fine
- Visit site B => Not working
- Reset cache on site B => Everythings works
- Visit site A => Not working

So the first site which loads the scripts from the CDN is the 'Winner' and that site works as expected.

I've tested it also by visiting: https://sample-collection.s3.amazonaws.com/advanced.html

After that I opened my development website and got this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/lmvworker.min.js'
> from origin 'https://dev-bdh-project-sharing-management.bdh.nl' has
> been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
> has a value 'https://sample-collection.s3.amazonaws.com' that is not
> equal to the supplied origin.

Answer (score 0):

As is suggested in the comments above - always use the below CDN URL to load Viewer:

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/style.min.css?v=v7.*
```

The other address is not recommended per our officially documentation.