# Autodesk Forge Cross-Origin Request Blocked Error

Tags: javascript, heroku, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We have web applications where we use Autodesk Forge viewer. These were working as usual until yesterday. We didn't make any changes for months for some of them and now out of nowhere, we are receiving Cross-Origin errors.
I have checked 3 of our web application with Forge, none of them are working! Firefox and Chrome give these kind of errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/res/locales/en/allstrings.json' from origin 'WEBSITE NAME' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:3000' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/lmvworker.min.js' from origin 'WEBSITE NAME' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:3000' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
```

and more png loading problems with errors above.

I don't know if it is because of deployment platform `heroku`. I need help on this since I have no idea what has changed. On the one of the platforms, there were made no changes since last year but it stopped working also.

I am using this url to load the viewer:

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/style.min.css?v=v7.*
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js
```

I need to mention that at localhost, Forge Viewer loads the model without CORS Error and works fine.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: We were also facing the same issue a few hours ago but now we are unable to reproduce it. Please check if it's working for you now.

Comment: Looks like the same situation as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62162175/cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-does-not-match-incorrect-access-co

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

According to @Can777, this issue was resolved by clearing browser history.

> The problem is solved by deleting the browser histories from all
> browsers (Firefox nearly didn't have any history actually, since we
> only use chrome).

=============

I'm sorry to hear this issue is bothering you. We have reported this issue to our engineering team to have a look. We will keep you updated once we got responses from them. We apologize for any problem that had caused to you.

Comment: Hello Eason, thank you for the quick response. The problem is solved by deleting the browser histories from all browsers (Firefox nearly didn't have any history actually, since we only use chrome). But I still don't know what was the real problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Can777 very glad to hear the issue was resolved. The root cause seems related to our recent service update this week. Our engineering team has fixed the problem today after we reported it to them. Apologizing for any inconvenience had caused to you.

Comment: Hi @Eason thanks a lot you for your help and quick response to the issue.